# Mesh doesn't move despite being a child of a metarig (Rigify)

Tags: rigging, rigify

First off, I'm pretty much a noob with Blender. Been fighting with this thing for many hours yesterday and probably would as many today, so wanted to ask here. What is wrong with my model? I followed MANY tutorials on YouTube on how to rigify a character model, and read up on countless threads, tried literally everything I have found. The rig itself seems fine, as it is a Rigify template. When I select my mesh, then Shift-select the rig, Ctrl+P and go with Automatic Weights, it creates the vertex groups and sets the parenting accordingly. However, when I move any bone in Pose mode, absolutely nothing happens on the mesh. The tutorials make it look so simple, and I can't believe this procedure could have been so unbelievably complicated. I'm at my wits end for this one, so I'd very much appreciate if someone could take a look and identify the problem.

[Here's a link to the .blend file](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aif3n8G4oCwWkZgkoE4V5uwVAbORTw?e=68QUUj), where I have reset the progress, leaving only the mesh and the rig (not parented).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Looks like the problem was solved. I just wanted to say that you should never parent the character to the metarig. I don't know, maybe it's just a mistake in the title... but you should always parent to the generated rig. The meta rig is only there to define the proportions of the generated rig.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error message when you try to parent *With Automatic Weight*, because of thousands of overlapping vertices. First apply the scale of your armature in *Object* mode. Select your mesh, go in *Edit* mode, select all and <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance*, it will remove thousands of overlapping vertices. Parent again and it will work.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't notice the error message anywhere, but had a hunch that the hair could mean trouble.

Comment: you're welcome. In my answer I meant apply the scale of the armature in Object mode